# How can I use Parallel Controller inside another Parallel Controller in Jmeter?

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Here I use Parallel Controller but the Parallel Controller2 and Parallel Controller3 don't run and throw error in logs. The Parallel Controller1 is inside Transaction Controller. The Parallel Controller2 and Parallel Controller3 are inside Simple Controller.

[image]

Here is the error log for Controller2

```
2021-08-24 17:51:48,819 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'bzm - Parallel Controller2'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to reset the thread context
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.setThreadContext(AbstractTestElement.java:579) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:623) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.JMeterThreadParallel.run(JMeterThreadParallel.java:61) [jmeter-parallel-0.11.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
```

How is it possible to execute the calls in parallel inside another parallel controller?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's supported, moreover it's not clear what you're trying to achieve by this.

As per [documentation](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) Parallel Controller **executes its children in parallel** so instead of going for nested constructions you can just place everything under a single Parallel Controller.

If you need to mimic a parallel call which in its turn triggers another parallel calls, however I don't think the use case is valid, you can reach out to the plugin developers and/or maintainers at [jmeter-plugins support forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

In the meantime you can use [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to kick off the parallel requests as per your network requests pattern using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language like it's described in the [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article